# Retrofit JSON Error parsing error

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, retrofit

Retrofit gives me this error when I try to parse the following JSON response

Raw

```
[{"DeviceName":"Samsung Galaxy A5","Brand":"Samsung"...},{"DeviceName":"Samsung Galaxy A5 Duos"... ...]
```

Pretty
[image: JSON Data]

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("/v1/getphone/")
Call<List<Phone>> getPhoneInfo(@Field("device") String device);
```

Java Class

```
public class Phone {
@SerializedName("DeviceName")
@Expose
public String DeviceName;
@SerializedName("Brand")
@Expose
public String Brand;
@SerializedName("technology")
@Expose
public String technology;
....
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put your Phone class inside another class as a list:

```
public class Root {

private List<Phone> phone;

//getters and setters here
}
```

and change this line:

```
Call<List<Phone>> getPhoneInfo(@Field("device") String device);
```

to

```
Call<Root> getPhoneInfo(@Field("device") String device);
```

Comment: doesn't work as @Rashid mentioned - "response doesn't have any array name"

Comment: Yes I missed that part

Answer (score 1):

In retrofit you need an array name to create a class with.your json is valid but the response doesn't have any array name so it won't be able to parse in that way.you have to parse it manually by getting json string from your response in retrofit like this

```
  ApiServiceClient.getApiService().yourFunctionName().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                try {
                    String jsonString=response.body().string();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().string());
                     //Parse your json here
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, is the any way to parse it using retrofit and not manualy.

Comment: As of now retrofit have not provide any solution for this.as per retrofit and google docs its a standard approach to start your json with and object and put array with its array name with it.other way is to parse manually

Comment: this works - [{"id":3,"name":"AA"},{"id":1,"name":"BB"},{"id":2,"name":"CC"},{"id":4,"name":"DD"}] ___ @GET("/v1/areas/") Call<List<Area>> getAreas(); But why isn't the other working???